# How to pass a command line argument to an angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line, environment-variables

I have a node.js angular application. First I build it and run it with node later on the dedicated server. How do I pass a value to my angular app? In the end I need to show a text on my UI based on the value of the command line argument.

Comment: Would you care to explain some more what it is you want to do? Are you running a nodejs backend with an Angular frontend, and want to start the node server with some arguments which is then passed on to the frontend and diplayed?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, according to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10521#issuecomment-390599462) reply from the angular-cli repo, passing command-line arguments from the CLI to the Angular app is intentionally not supported.

However, there's a workaround that is described [here](https://medium.com/bytelimes/angular-feature-flags-feature-toggle-applications-by-using-command-line-environment-variables-cca7b9e0ffb4) in depth, with a working example available at [github](https://github.com/nivrith/angular-commandline-env). In short, it does this by spawning `ng serve` as a child process using `spawn`, and then passing arguments as the environment variable to the child process using a Custom Webpack Config.